# I want to know the size of bounding box in object-detection api

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have used the `API`

**(https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection)**

And then,

How would I know the length of bounding box?

I have used Tutorial IPython notebook on github in real-time.

But I don't know use which command to calculate the length of boxes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It will be more useful to you and the other users of this forum, if you explain the question in more details. And also what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to extend Beta's answer:

You can get the predicted bounding boxes from the detection graph. An example for this is given in the [Tutorial IPython notebook on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb). This is where Beta's code snipped comes from. Access the `detection_graph` and extract the coordinates of the predicted bounding boxes from the tensor:

By calling `np.squeeze(boxes)` you reshape them to (m, 4), where m denotes the amount of predicted boxes. You can now access the boxes and compute the length, area or what ever you want.

But remember that the predicted box coordinates are normalized! They are in the following order:

`[ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]`

So computing the length in pixel would be something like:

```
def length_of_bounding_box(bbox):
    return bbox[3]*IMG_WIDTH - bbox[1]*IMG_WIDTH
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! !
But how can I "Access the detection_graph and extract the coordinates of the predicted bounding boxes from the tensor".
I'm not know clearly about the code.

Comment: @SUNJIAWEI you access the coordinates of the ith box with  `boxes[0][i]`

Comment: @iTiger I'm not sure if something has changed in tensorflow between the dates of the answers here (and below), but I was not getting the expected results when following the `[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]` convention. I had a look at the source code of the `draw_bounding_box_on_image_array` function on github on 08/02/2018 using this link ( https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py ) and the order is `[ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]`

Comment: @KolaB yes it looks like they changed the order of the coordinates. Thanks for your comment! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @ITiger the link specified by you is broken. I guess it was for older version. As of now I think the code in object_dectection.ipynb is also chnaged. What changes should I do to the new file so I get the co-ordinates of bounding box. When I print output_dict['detection_boxes'] i get 100 tuples for all the test images even for those on whom the model failed to predict. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a full answer on how to find the bounding box coordinates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110528/return-coordinates-for-bounding-boxes-googles-object-detection-api/47619424#47619424) and thought it might be useful to someone on this thread too.

Google Object Detection API returns bounding boxes in the format [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax] and in normalised form (full explanation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/image/working_with_bounding_boxes)). To find the (x,y) pixel coordinates we need to multiply the results by width and height of the image. First get the width and height of your image:

```
width, height = image.size
```

Then, extract ymin,xmin,ymax,xmax from the `boxes` object and multiply to get the (x,y) coordinates:

```
ymin = boxes[0][i][0]*height
xmin = boxes[0][i][1]*width
ymax = boxes[0][i][2]*height
xmax = boxes[0][i][3]*width
```

Finally print the coordinates of the box corners:

```
print 'Top left'
print (xmin,ymin,)
print 'Bottom right'
print (xmax,ymax)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call boxes, like the following:

```
boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
```

similarly for scores, and classes.

Then just call them in session run.

```
(boxes, scores, classes) = sess.run(
              [boxes, scores, classes],
              feed_dict={image_tensor: imageFile})
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer!
However, after calling boxes, how could I got the length in session?

Comment: @SUNJIAWEI: If you check the boxes values, it will give you the coordinates of the objects. Suppose you are checking if the image has a person or not. The boxes give you the coordinates (or location) where the person exists in the image. If you want just length of the person, you can extract the length of the person.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can get all those from the graph

```
image_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
boxes = graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
scores = graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
classes = graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
num_detections = graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
```

and boxes[0] contains all predicted bounding box coordinate in format of [top_left_x, top_left_y, bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y], which is what you are looking for.

Check out this repo and you may find more details: 
https://github.com/KleinYuan/tf-object-detection

Answer (score 0):

The following code that recognizes objects and returns the information for the locations and confidence is:

```
(boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
```

To iterate through the boxes

```
 for i,b in enumerate(boxes[0]):
```

To get width and height:

```
 width = boxes[0][i][1]+boxes[0][i][3]
 height = boxes[0][i][0]+boxes[0][i][2]
```

You can find more details: [https://pythonprogramming.net/detecting-distances-self-driving-car/]