# Return coordinates for bounding boxes Google's Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

How can i get the coordinates of the produced bounding boxes using the inference script of Google's Object Detection API? I know that printing boxes[0][i] returns the predictions of the ith detection in an image but what exactly is the meaning of these returned numbers? Is there a way that i can get xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are happy with my answer feel free to mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google Object Detection API returns bounding boxes in the format [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax] and in normalised form (full explanation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image#Working_with_Bounding_Boxes/)). To find the (x,y) pixel coordinates we need to multiply the results by width and height of the image. First get the width and height of your image:

```
width, height = image.size
```

Then, extract ymin,xmin,ymax,xmax from the `boxes` object and multiply to get the (x,y) coordinates:

```
ymin = boxes[0][i][0]*height
xmin = boxes[0][i][1]*width
ymax = boxes[0][i][2]*height
xmax = boxes[0][i][3]*width
```

Finally print the coordinates of the box corners:

```
print 'Top left'
print (xmin,ymin,)
print 'Bottom right'
print (xmax,ymax)
```

Comment: Any explanation for why this is done? Your link is dead. Is it because the input images get resized to a standard size? And that normalised coordinates are useful to work any sized input?

Comment: is `image` a numpy array? If so `image.size` gives number of elements in the array, and `image.shape` gives dimensions of the image. But I thought it gives number of rows, then number of columns for a matrix i.e. `height, width = image.shape`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, yes that would make sense. Lots of sizing and resizing in neural networks.

Comment: @KolaB Expect the docs to keep moving for some time to come. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image#Working_with_Bounding_Boxes/

Comment: @Gal_M Thanks for the updated link. My comment was about the line in your answer that says `width, height = image.size`. I think this should be `height, width = image.shape[:2]`. I still think so after reading the updated link. The very first section "Encoding and Decoding" says "*Encoded images are represented by scalar string Tensors, decoded images by 3-D uint8 tensors of* ***shape*** `[height, width, channels]`. It would be great if you can clarify why you use `width, height = image.size`.

Comment: The link to the documentation is dead.

Comment: Does the `boxes` object still work? I cannot find it.

Answer (score 3):

The boxes array that you mention contains this information and the format is a [N, 4] array where each row is of the format:
[ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax] in normalized coordinates relative to the size of the input image.