# Is there a way to only detect objects with width > 200px in tensorflow?

Tags: object, tensorflow, detection, object-detection

Is there a way filter object detection with width?

Assuming that I have to detect apples with WIDTH > 100 Pixels. Is there a build-in tensorflow function to do that? or do I have to condition the code myself before drawing the bounding box?

Comment: Make your question a bit clearer. What model do you use, on which images are you going to use it, etc?

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about applying object detection with a convolutional neural network is its ability to detect objects with an invariance against the size of the object. So the way to solve your problem would be to get the predicted bounding boxes and only accept the ones, that have a width > 100 pixels.

Here you can see, how to access the bounding box coordinates:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46169885/6251391